# Unable to install NGINX module on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am having NGINX 1.4.6 version installed on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine and i want to install [ngx_http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) module on my machine .To install this module I searched lot on google and this are my findings on it.

`./configure --with-pcre=/home/USER/DOWNLOADS/pcre-8.37/` when i am trying to run `./configure` command i got error as `-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`.So when I search for configure file for nginx i am unable to see this file for given loacation( etc/nginx/). And I am new to Ubuntu so please suggest me that what I am doing is the correct way of compiling NGINX module or not.

Comment: Real IP module is already build in nginx package

Comment: @Alexey Ten so how to compile it can you please help me on this I am new to Ubuntu and NGINX

Comment: Why do you want to compile it? Just use precompiled version.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I need to Restoring the original visitor IP for my web application for cloud flare so the cloud flare team recommended me to install ngx_http_realip_module module

Comment: It is already there if you use default nginx from ubuntu repos

Comment: @Alexey Ten can you please tell me how to use it

Comment: or is there any blog so that i can follow the steps to configure it on my server

Comment: There is. Google «cloud flare nginx real ip»

Comment: I have already looked into this link .My issue is This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_realip_module configuration parameter

Comment: So how and where I need to specify this parameter in nginx which is installed on my server

Comment: OMG. Once again. It **is already built** in Ubuntu package. Just configure server as cloud flare recommends…

Comment: ok got it thanks now i found it by executing nginx -V commad

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.